# RouteData lost on Post in a controller called by RenderAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction, routedata

I have a "Resume" view which makes a call to RenderAction so I can add comments to a resume. Code:

```
    @{Html.RenderAction("Add", "ResumeComment", new { resumeId = @Model.Id });}
```

So the code above calls Add action in my ResumeComment controller and passes it resumeId. If I take a look at my ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData inside the Add (GET) method, I see 4 values:

```
PL <- which is resume category
954 <- resume id
Resume <- Controller
Edit <- Action, because I am adding comments on the Edit page in the resume.

The problem that I have is that I am loosing resume category (PL) and resume id(954) when I post (add a comment). Here is my ResumeComment form:

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "ResumeComment"))
    {
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />   

    ..}

So this form will call Add (Post) method in the ResumeComment controller when sumitted. Here is my add method:


    [HttpPost, ActionName("Add")]  
    public ActionResult Add(ResumeComment resumeComment)
    {
    .....
    }

I am not able to access ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData at all, it is null. I am however able to access ControllerContext.RouteData but when I look at the values I only see "ResumeComment" and "Add" in there and that is it. How can I preserve the resume category and resume id?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post some values in your form to `ResumeComment.Add` you need to put them in hidden inputs. `RouteData` is not in any magic way persisted between requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TempData](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/07/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/)- its like session but once you read the data from it is deleted.
Its a good solution to store temporary data between two sequential requests.